# How to submit login form in Rvest package w/o button argument

Tags: r, web-scraping, forms, rvest

I am trying to scrape a web page that requires authentication using html_session() & html_form() from the rvest package.
I found this e.g. provided by Hadley Wickham, but am not able to customize it to my case.

```
united <- html_session("http://www.united.com/")
account <- united %>% follow_link("Account")
login <- account %>%
         html_nodes("form") %>%
         extract2(1) %>%
         html_form() %>%
         set_values(
                `ctl00$ContentInfo$SignIn$onepass$txtField` = "GY797363",
                `ctl00$ContentInfo$SignIn$password$txtPassword` = password)
account <- account %>% 
submit_form(login, "ctl00$ContentInfo$SignInSecure")
```

In my case, I can't find the values to set in the form, hence I am trying to give the user and pass directly:
    set_values("email","password")

I also don't know how to refer to submit button, so I tried:
    submit_form(account,login)

The error I got for the submit_form function is:
    Error in names(submits)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Any idea on how to go about this is appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 12):

Currently, this issue is the same as the open [issue #159](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/issues/159) in the `rvest` package, which causes issues where not all fields in a form have a `type` value. This buy may be fixed in a future release.

However, we can work around the issue by monkey patching the underlying function `rvest:::submit_request`.

The core problem is the helper function `is_submit`. Initially, it's defined like this:

```
is_submit <- function(x) tolower(x$type) %in% c("submit", 
        "image", "button")
```

As logical as this is, however, it fails in two scenarios:

1. There is no `type` element.
2. The `type` element is `NULL`.

*Both* of these happen to occur on the United login form. We can resolve this by adding two checks inside the function.

```
custom.submit_request <- function (form, submit = NULL) 
{
  is_submit <- function(x) {
    if (!exists("type", x) | is.null(x$type)){
      return(F);
    }
    tolower(x$type) %in% c("submit", "image", "button")
  } 
  submits <- Filter(is_submit, form$fields)
  if (length(submits) == 0) {
    stop("Could not find possible submission target.", call. = FALSE)
  }
  if (is.null(submit)) {
    submit <- names(submits)[[1]]
    message("Submitting with '", submit, "'")
  }
  if (!(submit %in% names(submits))) {
    stop("Unknown submission name '", submit, "'.\n", "Possible values: ", 
         paste0(names(submits), collapse = ", "), call. = FALSE)
  }
  other_submits <- setdiff(names(submits), submit)
  method <- form$method
  if (!(method %in% c("POST", "GET"))) {
    warning("Invalid method (", method, "), defaulting to GET", 
            call. = FALSE)
    method <- "GET"
  }
  url <- form$url
  fields <- form$fields
  fields <- Filter(function(x) length(x$value) > 0, fields)
  fields <- fields[setdiff(names(fields), other_submits)]
  values <- pluck(fields, "value")
  names(values) <- names(fields)
  list(method = method, encode = form$enctype, url = url, values = values)
}
```

To monkey patch, we need to use the `R.utils` package (install via `install.packages("R.utils")` if you don't have it).

```
library(R.utils)

reassignInPackage("submit_request", "rvest", custom.submit_request)
```

From there, we can issue our own request.

```
account <- account %>% 
     submit_form(login, "ctl00$ContentInfo$SignInSecure")
```

And that works!

(Well, "works" is a misnomer. Due to United employing more aggressive authentication requirements -- including known browsers -- this results in a `301 Unauthorized`. However, it fixes the error).

A full reproducible example involved a couple of other minor code changes:

```
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/account/account.aspx"
account <- html_session(url)
login <- account %>%
  html_nodes("form") %>%
  extract2(1) %>%
  html_form() %>%
  set_values(
    `ctl00$ContentInfo$SignIn$onepass$txtField` = "USER",
    `ctl00$ContentInfo$SignIn$password$txtPassword` = "PASS")
account <- account %>% 
  submit_form(login, "ctl00$ContentInfo$SignInSecure")
```